# How to play an .swf (sound) when a div/image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have been searching on the web how this can be done for the past 2 hours or so and haven't made any progress..

So basically I want nav.swf to play when an image is clicked.

Code for nav.swf:

```
object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="1" height="1" id="nav" align="middle">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
            <param name="movie" value="nav.swf" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    <embed src="nav.swf" menu="false" quality="high" wmode="transparent" play="false" flashvars="autoplay=false&play=false bgcolor="#ffffff" width="1" height="1" name="nav" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

.swf files are Flash video files. Follow these approaches to play .swf files.

**Method 1:**

You can add the object element and set the attributes on the `"onclick"` event of the div/image.
And then set the `"autostart"` attribute to true. This should do the trick.

We will add the object element inside the below div.

```
<div id="video_wrapper"></div>
```

Assuming the div id as "video_div", on which the uer will click, use the below code.

```
document.getElementById("video_div").addEventListener("click", playVideo);

function playVideo() {

    var obj = document.createElement('object');
    obj.setAttribute('data', 'nav.swf');
    obj.setAttribute('autostart', true);
    obj.setAttribute('play', true);
    document.getElementById('video_wrapper').appendChild(obj);
}
```

Also check **[swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)**

**Method2:**
You can call Actionscript functions from Javascript using ExternalInterface.
Refer the documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm really new to JS. Where do I place `document.getElementById("video_div").addEventListener("click", playVideo);` ?

Comment: You need to place this, in your window.onload code. If you're using jQuery, then you can put inside $(document).ready function.

Comment: Does it have the same effect as onclick="playVideo() ?

Comment: Yes. Both have the same effect.

Comment: Ok, it's working but the .swf starts playing 30 seconds after the <div> is clicked.. why so? Is it possible to change this value play="false" in the embed code to play="true" instead?

Comment: Hmm, It should start playing instantly. Does it appear black for 30 seconds?

Comment: the swf is 1px by 1px so I can't really judge :/ EDIT: I just noticed it loads instantly on Chrome but takes ages on Firefox

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the Browser plugin. Which plugin you are using?

Comment: Is it possible to change the value play="false" in the embed code to play="true" instead?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean, instead of creating a new object, changing the "play="false" value of an existing object to "play=true, hence playing the .swf.

Comment: This needs to happen only on the click event, as per your requirement. If you set the play property to true in your HTML code, it will start playing even before the click event.

Comment: I mean, instead of creating a new object, changing the "play="false" value of an existing object to "play=true (by means of a Javascript code) when the image is clicked, hence playing the .swf.

Comment: I don't think that would work. Best way is to remove the older object and then create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

use External Interface. AS3 code:

```
//call from javascript
ExternalInterface.addCallback("playSoundInFlash", as3Function);

function as3Function():void
{
    // play sound here
}
```

in JS, do something like:

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName]
    }
    else {
        return document[movieName]
    }
}
function playSound () {
    thisMovie("nav.swf").playSoundInFlash();
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="myimage.jpg" onclick="javascript: playSound();" />
</body>
```